# Two-Way Data Binding not working when applying function on value

Tags: angular, forms, two-way-binding

I am trying to implement two-way data binding for my input field.

It is working as expected if I use the value directly. By working I mean that the value changes immediately when typing/changing the input field value.

However, I would like to "replace" the value with its corresponding value from a map.

```
<mat-form-field class="steuersatz">
    <input matInput placeholder="EU Taxcode" type="text" formControlName="euTaxCode" [matTooltip]="'EU Taxcode'" [matTooltipPosition]="'above'"/>
    <button mat-button matSuffix mat-icon-button (click)="edit('euTaxCode', $event)">
          <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
    </button>
</mat-form-field>

<div class="taxcodeName">
    <p>{{taxcodeName}}</p>
</div>
```

Works:

```
// taxcode, taxcodeName
taxcodes = new Map();

this.taxForm.get('euTaxCode').valueChanges.pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)).subscribe(data => {
  // data = euTaxCode
  this.taxcodeName = data;
});
```

Does not work:

```
// taxcode, taxcodeName
taxcodes = new Map();

this.taxForm.get('euTaxCode').valueChanges.pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)).subscribe(data => {
  // data = euTaxCode
  this.taxcodeName = taxcodesList.get(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to convert the data from string to number with `parseInt()`. Thus, it was neither a problem with the data binding in general nor with the get function.